# Treadmill controller with failures: Dying capacitor or other issue?

Tags: capacitor, error

I own a Kettler Marathon treadmill from about 2002.

For a while now, the controller has had some failures/interruptions. Sometimes the display goes blank for a second and you lose the data from the current training sessions, but it keeps running (the belt keeps moving) and restarts counting. In other cases, it just stops completely (even the belt.) The problems only occur when you hit a button to change a setting.

My first suspicion was a loose cable, so I opened up the casing of the controller.
Then I discovered this:

[image]

[image]

This capacitor is leaking, right? Is this maybe related to the [capacitor plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor_plague) I learned about today? CapXon is a Taiwanese company.  Do the described symptoms not match a dying capacitor and I have yet another problem?

**Edit**
I removed the board from the treadmill. I discovered a second capacitor with that "yellow stuff" around it. Here's a picture from close-up:

[image]

Comment: (That may just be hot glue. Have you looked for and removed dust build-up? Unplugging and replugging connectors that look repluggable may help, too. Wait, this is going the direction of repair, which I remember to be off-topic.)

Comment: @greybeard: Checking the connectors was what I was going for when I discovered that "yellow stuff". It's a lot of screws to open and close that controller, so I'm trying to figure out if this capacitor is bad before I close it and reopen it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “stuff” you see is (quite appropriately) sometimes called *snot*, and is a polymer compound glue used to mechanically fix the components to the PCB.

Capacitor leakage would look differently and can be quite insidious, since it will corrode the traces and vias on the PCB. The electrolyte spewed from the capacitors is slightly slimy/slippery, almost like a very thin layer of oil. It may appear transparent, but can also turn brownish.

The capacitors may still be bad without any leakage or other visible failures. Once you unsolder them to test them, there’s no point in keeping them though - just replace them if you worry about them. I’m not convinced yet these little capacitors caused the issue. It almost seems like the mechanical pressure on the keypad causes something to bend and misbehave.

Answer (score 2):

As Kuba says, that stuff is a kind of adhesive intended to keep the caps from flopping around and the leads breaking off. One manufacturer describes it as a flame-retardant synthetic rubber. I keep a tube of the yellowish stuff around for small repairs, but manufacturers buy it in tubs or drums.

It may indeed be a capacitor, however it would not tend to be the smallish parts that you see. If the treadmill has a separate wall-wart the degraded capacitor could be internal to that device, and that would be the first thing I would investigate. Normally one would simply replace the wall wart, however it's sometimes possible to fix or otherwise mitigate the degradation.

Assuming there is an external wall wart, one way to check it without sophisticated equipment would be to power the device (testing must be done under load) and measuring the wall-wart output on a multimeter in DC volts mode. Then switch to AC volts and measure the ripple. Most multimeters are AC coupled in AC volts mode so they will show just the ripple (for example, a 9V battery would measure 0.00V). If the multimeter shows more than a couple hundred mV AC from the wall-wart under load then it is suspicious.